# Cancelling drinking and launching potions on bukkit 1.8

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How can I check if the player throws or drink a specific potion? I want to cancel some specific potions to be used in my project.

As far as I know, there isn't a method call when the player tries to throw a potion, nor when he finishes drinking it.

I have found a method that is called when the player Right Click an Item, but I want to detect only when it is drank or thrown.

How can I cancel the events that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify if a player consumed a potion you can use a `PlayerItemConsume event`:

```
@EventHandler
public void onItemConsume (PlayerItemConsumeEvent e) {
    ItemStack consumed = e.getItem();
    //Make your checks if this is the Potion you want to cancel

    if (/*conditions*/) e.setCancelled(true);    //Will cancel the potion drink, not applying the effects nor using the item.
}
```

---

---

To check which potion was thrown by a player, you can use a ProjectileLaunchEvent

```
@EventHandler
public void onProjectileLaunch(ProjectileLaunchEvent e) {
    Projectile projectile = e.getEntity();
    //Make the checks to know if this is the potion you want to cancel
    if (/*conditions*/) e.setCancelled(true);   //Cancels the potion launching
}
```

### ----------

For example, if I want to cancel the drink action of a Health Potion:

```
@EventHandler
public void onItemConsume (PlayerItemConsumeEvent e) {
    ItemStack consumed = e.getItem();
    if (consumed.getType.equals(Material.POTION) {
        //It's a potion
        Potion potion = Potion.fromItemStack(consumed);
        PotionType type = potion.getType();
        if (type.equals(PotionType.INSTANT_HEAL) e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

And if I want to Cancel a PotionThrow:

```
@EventHandler
public void onProjectileLaunch(ProjectileLaunchEvent e) {
    Projectile projectile = e.getEntity();

    if (projectile instanceof ThrownPotion) {
       //It's a Potion
       ThrownPotion pot = (ThrownPotion) projectile;
       Collection<PotionEffect> effects = pot.getEffects();
       for (PotionEffect p : effects) {
           if (p.getType().equals(PotionEffectType.INSTANT_HEAL)){
               e.setCancelled(true);
               break;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to create an array with potions and throwable potions (so 2 arrays), what type the both arrays have to be?

Comment: Can you give an Example on some Potions (because I only find "option" not the specific ones)

Comment: for example an array of throwable potions of strength and instant health

Comment: that i can compare with the Projectile (e.getEntity())

Comment: @EventHandler
 public void onItemConsume (PlayerItemConsumeEvent event) {
     ItemStack consumed = event.getItem();
     if(consumed.getType().equals(Material.POTION)) {
         Potion potion = Potion.fromItemStack(consumed);
         PotionType type = potion.getType();
         for(int i = 0; i<main.getIllegalPotions().length; i++){
          if(type.equals(main.getIllegalPotions()[i])){
           event.setCancelled(true);
          }
         }
     }
 }

Comment: If i drink the potion nothing happens :c

Comment: And how can I check if a crafted gold-apple is an op-gold apple

Comment: I solved it already

How can I check if someone uses a saddle or an op gold-apple?

If you tell me that I know everything I need for my plugin :)

Comment: You can check if the item consumed is a golden-apple, and if it's value is Enchanted-Golden-Apple. Try to figure the saddle by yourself, no more spoonfeeding :)

Comment: If i gove out the ID it allways says "322", but for bith kinds of apple

How can I check if its an op g.?

Comment: You have to check for the damage value

Comment: Thanks I did it:D

Whats the method thats called when a creeper explodes or the world gets destroyed?

Comment: That's not in the scope of this question. If this answer solved your issue, make sure to mark it as the right one (clicking on the check mark), and feel free to ask another question regarding your other concern!